# FTS (Contains) is not searching string with underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure for search that uses FTS . In table we have a string like '1_2_3'.

When we exec the proc to search for 1 , this returns the record with 1_2_3
if we search with 2 or 3 then the record with the string value '1_2_3' is not being fetched.

Input for search parameter is '"2*"'/'"3*"'

In where Clause i'm using

```
CONTAINS(dp.*, @SearchText)
```

Edit :-

```
create proc search_Profile (@searchstr)
as
select * from profile where CONTAINS(dp.*, @SearchText)
```

The table profile has record with profile name as 
  `'1_2_3'`

When i execute proc `search_Profile '"1*"'
output will include the row with`1_2_3'

```
exec search_profile '"2*"'
```

Will not return the record `1_2_3` though it contains 2 in it

Comment: will you please elaborate with one more example.

Comment: @user3864233  is it clear now